# Get the count of columns with respect to the value stored in it using SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there are employee details. In the table there is column named `Active`. If that is `1` then the employee is active or else not.
I have to show a column showing the count of Active employees and Inactive employees.

How can I do this?
I have not done anything because I know that I cannot use directly `where` clause in here. It is in SQL Server.

Table is like:

```
Sno   Name   Active
____________________
1.   John      1
2.    Yuri     0
3.    Cody     1
4.    Ravi     1
5.    Tom      1
6.    Jessy    0


The resultant table :
Active   Inactive
___________________
4           2
```

I have to further group it by departments and maybe centers but I am stuck.

Thanks for help in advance. I would also love if you share any resource regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` like this way :

```
select sum(case active when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Active, 
sum(case when active<>1 then 1 else 0 end) as Inactive
from Table1
```

[SQL Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6ebd7/5)

Answer (score 1):

Just use aggregation:

```
select sum(active) as numactive, sum(1 - active) as numinactive
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the aggregated data.

```
declare @active int, @inactive int


select @active = count(active)
from TableName
where active = 1


select @inactive = count(active)
from TableName
where active = 0

select @active as [Active], @inactive as [InActive]
```

You can also add the following code to insert into a temp table (directly after the code above):

```
into #tmpTable

select * from #tmpTable
```

That way you can join the temp table to other tables if needed (of course you would have to add a key to the temp table to do this).